# Watch Face does not show up on Android Wear app

Tags: android, wear-os

I developed a custom watch face (Android Wear 5), works perfectly during testing. Uploaded to Google Play and download to test, but it does not show up in the Android Wear app, nor the paired watch itself (running Android Wear 5.0.1)!

I uploaded the mobile apk (similar to my other Android Wear apps), and also have the same permissions for both mobile and wear.

Anybody encountered similar problem? Here's the Watch Face if anybody wanted to test it out: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.virtualgs.retrowatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you received an update to your watch face already? You will only see the new watch faces after an update.

If you do have an updated watch, try going to the Android Wear app on your phone, Settings -> Resync apps.

EDIT:

I looked into the logcat of the watch and I saw an attempt to install your watch package:

```
I/WearablePkgInstaller(  582): Sending install intent to PackageInstaller Intent { act=com.google.android.clockwork.packagemanager.INSTALL_PACKAGE dat=content://com.google.android.clockwork.home.provider/host/com.virtualgs.retrowatch/wearable/com.virtualgs.retrowatch/apk typ=vnd.android.cursor.item/wearable_apk pkg=com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller (has extras) }
W/WearablePkgInstaller( 1859): Wearable com.virtualgs.retrowatch has a permission "android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND" that is not granted in the host application.
```

You forgot to add `PROVIDE_BACKGROUND` permission to you phone app (wearable permission set has to be subset of the phone permission set). Remember, that you also need wake lock permission, in case you didn't add it.

EDIT2:

You are declaring wrong permission for providing background. This is the correct one:

`com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66845/discussion-between-lim-thye-chean-and-gruszczy).

Comment: Yha, the Watchface Sample in the SDK isn't real clear.  neither app has a default activity - and you launch them - and they don't show up...

Comment: Yes, there are no default activities, because for watch face configurations are explicitly launched either from UI on the watch or from the UI in Android Wear app.

Comment: I have been testing letting user do some simple configuration from the watch face - and still not successful after a full day or reading and writing codes. Think it is unnecessary complicated when configure on the wear itself (not from phone) and the watch face needs the GoogleApiClient messaging at all? Hope there a simple way like setting some SharedPreferences and read it on the watch face.

Comment: If all your configuration lives on the wearable, you don't need message and SharedPreferences should be enough. Consider asking another question and presenting your design.

Comment: Install Application part on the phone and Wearable part on the watch. How to do this with Android Studio?

Comment: do I need to upload the App to Google Play? Or can I just run it from Android Studio? Because I never see the WatchFace on the phone or on the watch. Don't get it to run

Comment: Having the same problem here, but no logcat message.
Developed in eclipse (not in Android Studio), on the emulator i can use my watch face but in the Android Wear app its nothing to see?! Both apps (phone and watch) are signed, watch apk is in the res/raw folder